# Disable a <tr> where one of its <td> contains any value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple trs and tds within them. Each td contains a different element name for one particular field I need to work out if there is text in there or not. If there is text in that field then i want the whole tr to be disabled or ideally hidden from selection (because there is a radio button i dont want the user to click if this td contains any text)

The table construct is below, sorry its a screensnip

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYMAY.jpg

I tried something to try and find elements like the name which has the text, then if it has text, hide its parent i.e. the whole row, if not do nothing...this just doesnt do anything !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name^="ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_rpVacantTime_ct"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text()) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        } else {
            alert($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

So ideally, I would expect the above to find all elements that have that similar name then hide its parent row.

Comment: Post actual code, not pictures of code. We expect your question to contain the relevant "*[mcve]*" code in order to reproduce your problem and aid others, in future, to be able to search more easily for answers to their own questions based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the label then traverse up the tree to the `tr` if conditions are met.

You can use the jquery "ends with" selector `$=` to select the labels without all the ugly asp.net id's.

```
$("span[id$='lblReservationReason']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 0){
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

**Edit**

To disable the radio when you get your row you can go back down the tree using `find`

```
$("span[id$='lblReservationReason']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 0){
        let radio = $(this).closest('tr')
                    .find('input[type="radio"][name="rbVacantTime"]');

        $(radio).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: really neat thanks, if i wanted to still show it but disable the clicking of the radio button, how could I do that? I tried             $(this).closest('tr').removeAttr("onclick");